# Aligning icons to simple search bar

Tags: html, css, button, input

I am editing a simple search bar. My plan is to have two buttons above the search bar, that are responsive. With one button floating to the right and one button floating to the left.

However, I cannot seem to get the buttons to stop coming out they are not inline with the search bar, almost "Out of its container".

**Code:**

```css
.container {
  float: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#falist, #faupload {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 25px;
}
#falist {
  float: left;
}
#faupload {
  float: right;
}
input {
  border: 1px solid #F1F;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 35px;
}
span.clear { clear: left; display: block; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Search</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel=stylesheet href=https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="icons">
  <div id="falist"><i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div id="faupload"><i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <span class="clear"></span>
</div>
<div class="searchbar">
  <input id="searchbox" type="search"/>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Image:**

[image]

Comment: can you re-arrange the html?

Comment: Did you try setting the `margin-left `and `margin-right` for the `.icons` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:
.Wrap your inner elements of container in another wrap, and set the margin on that element.
Option 2:
Is in snippet, apply margin to icons, and input itself. I added 3 lines of code to your snippet.

```css
.container {
  float: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#falist, #faupload {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 25px;
}
#falist {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 35px; /* 1) MOVING FIRST IMAGE FROM SIDE */
}
#faupload {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 35px; /* 2) MOVING 2ND IMAGE FROM RIGHT SIDE */
}
input {
  border: 1px solid #F1F;
  width: calc(100% - 70px); /* 3) 100% - HOW MUCH MARGIN DO YOU WANT AROUND INPUT?  */
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 0 35px; /* 4) APPLY MARGIN TO INPUT */
}
span.clear { clear: left; display: block; }
```

```html
    <link rel=stylesheet href=https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css>
<div class="container">
  <div class="icons">
  <div id="falist"><i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div id="faupload"><i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <span class="clear"></span>
</div>
<div class="searchbar">
  <input id="searchbox" type="search"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it using flexbox, with much more less code in CSS and in HTML

```css
.container,
.icons {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%
}

.icons {
  justify-content: space-between
}

.searchbar {
  flex: 1
}

#searchbox {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="icons">
    <div id="falist">
      <i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="faupload">
      <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="searchbar">
    <input id="searchbox" type="search" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: OK i misunderstood the question, the answer was updated, so the downvoter can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

take out that `clear:left` from `span.clear`

Snippet below

```css
.container {
  float: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align:top;
}
#falist, #faupload {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 25px;
}
#falist {
  float: left;
}
#faupload {
  float: right;
}
input {
  border: 1px solid #F1F;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 35px;
}
span.clear { display: block; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Search</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel=stylesheet href=https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="icons">
  <div id="falist"><i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div id="faupload"><i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <span class="clear"></span>
  <div class="searchbar">
  <input id="searchbox" type="search"/>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.icons{
  margin-left: 37px;
  margin-right: 37px;
}
```

This works to get them on top where the red boxes are. If not exactly, just tweak them.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by adding the following code to the element `.icons` hope it helps!

```
.icons{
    margin: 0 31px;
}
```

```css
.container {
  float: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#falist, #faupload {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 25px;
}
#falist {
  float: left;
}
#faupload {
  float: right;
}
input {
  border: 1px solid #F1F;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 35px;
}
span.clear { clear: left; display: block; }

.icons{
    margin: 0 31px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Search</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel=stylesheet href=https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="icons">
  <div id="falist"><i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div id="faupload"><i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <span class="clear"></span>
</div>
<div class="searchbar">
  <input id="searchbox" type="search"/>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```